# backslash and \xnnn conversion to ascii

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, python-3.7

I am reading from a file the path for some jpg files and the format is:

```
...
prc103\CV137\2018\09\14\21\103137435939720180914210353_F01.jpg
prc103\CV137\2018\09\14\21\103137435940120180914210820_F01.jpg
prc103\CV137\2018\09\14\21\103137435946020180914215915_F01.jpg
...
```

I want to change some characteristics of this path but when I try to manipulate the string I have no success because it changed to this:

```
'prc103\\CV137\x818\x009\x0c\x11C137435939720180914210353_F01.jpg'
```

How to have the original clean ascii string ?

Comment: Show the code you're using to read the paths

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on ["Lexical analysis"](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

> The backslash () character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

You can find more examples of such ["escape sequences"](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html) in the documentation or see for yourself by opening a Python  shell (i.e. typing in `\2018`, which will return `\x818`, as in your example).

Is the file you're reading accessible to you? Try to find and replace the backslashes in your text file with forward slashes.